# XML parsing in java

Tags: java, android, xml

Using SAX parser in Java, how to do attribute based parsing.

Suppose my xml file is as follows,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<employees category="1" type="regular" location="india">
    <employee name="xyz" doj="20/12/2001" dob="21/12/1988" salary="12000"></employee>
    <employee name="xyz" doj="22/12/2003" dob="22/12/1988" salary="18000"></employee>
    <employee name="xyz" doj="23/12/2002" dob="23/12/1988" salary="15000"></employee>
    <employee name="xyz" doj="24/12/2003" dob="22/12/1988" salary="17000"></employee>
    <employee name="xyz" doj="26/12/2005" dob="24/12/1988" salary="12000"></employee>

</employees>
```

I want to fetch the each attribute values of employee element. Please help me out

Comment: What you have provided is not helpful.  Would it not make sense to also show your parsing code?

Comment: He is also missing a question. I can't find a question mark...

Comment: I have edited the question. Please help me out on this

Comment: Guys due to my mistake in this question I am unable post questions here. My account is disabled. Please up-vote on this post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DefaultHandler` class provides a callback to listen for start elements, and it has a signature that contains an `Attributes` object, representing the attributes of that element.

[`startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/xml/sax/helpers/DefaultHandler.html#startElement%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20org.xml.sax.Attributes%29)

Looking at the `Attributes` interface, I see methods to help you out.

1. If you don't know which attributes you are interested in, and you want to look at all attributes, you should use `getLength()`, and the do a `for-loop` over that length, looking at each attributes `getLocalName(int)` or `getQName(int)`, and you can find its value by calling `getValue(int)` (all `int`'s are used as indices into the attributes list).
2. If you do know which attributes you are interested in, you can simply call `getValue(String)`, passing in the string name of the attribute you are after.

Here is some example code that could get you the names and values of all attributes of a given element:

```
public void startElement(String ns, String localName, String qName, Attributes attrs) throws SAXException {
    for(int i = 0; i < attrs.getLength(); ++i) {
        String attrName = attrs.getLocalName(i);
        String attrValue = attrs.getValue(i);

        //do stuff with name/value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SAX programming can be very confusing if you're not used to it.  Constructing the parser is a bit tricky because you have to struggle with the abstract Interface API.  Once you get it all going and register your handler though, accessing the attributes should be straightforward; your handler class need to implement the method:

```
public void startElement(String nsUri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) 
        throws SAXException
```

The attribute values are available in the arg of that name.